# Monitoring heap in java android app

Tags: android, eclipse, heap-memory, ddms

The screen shot below shows DDMS in Eclipse monitoring the heap in an Android app (top, in red rectangle). In the LogCat window at the bottom, I have output of this statement:
`Log.e("HEAP", "native, " + android.os.Debug.getNativeHeapSize() + "  allocated, " + android.os.Debug.getNativeHeapAllocatedSize());`
I would have expected these numbers to be the same, but they are not, so clearly my expectations are incorrect. Can you tell me what these numbers really are?

[image: DDMS screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

There was a very good session on this topic held by Google at Google IO 2011.

Here is the link : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk

In this video he has explained each and every GC parameter.